Pass a Table-Valued Parameter (TVP) to a SQL Server stored procedure using VBA and ADO
Question: I need to pass a table-valued parameter (TVP) to a SQL Server stored procedure from VBA using ADO. Here's the scenario:
I have a SQL Server TYPE and stored procedure defined like this:
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyTableType AS TABLE 
(
    StatusCategoryId SMALLINT,
    StatusKeyId SMALLINT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedureWithTVP
    @MyTableParam dbo.MyTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @MyTableParam;
END;
GO

From VBA, I want to create a Recordset dynamically and pass it as the @MyTableParam to the stored procedure.
Here's my VBA code:
Sub PassTVP()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rsTVP As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter

    ' Create and open connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    conn.Open

    ' Create and configure Recordset for TVP
    Set rsTVP = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rsTVP
        .Fields.Append "StatusCategoryId", adSmallInt
        .Fields.Append "StatusKeyId", adSmallInt
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
        .Open

        ' Add data to Recordset
        .AddNew
        .Fields("StatusCategoryId").Value = 1
        .Fields("StatusKeyId").Value = 1
        .Update

        .AddNew
        .Fields("StatusCategoryId").Value = 1
        .Fields("StatusKeyId").Value = 2
        .Update

        ' Disconnect the Recordset
        .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With

    ' Create command and add TVP parameter
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = "dbo.MyProcedureWithTVP"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

        ' Add TVP parameter
        Set prm = .CreateParameter("@MyTableParam", adVariant, adParamInput, , rsTVP)
        .Parameters.Append prm

        ' Execute the stored procedure
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub

When I run this code, I get this error in this line:

Add TVP parameter
Set prm = .CreateParameter("@MyTableParam", adVariant, adParamInput, , rsTVP)


Run-time error '3001': Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Is it possible to pass a TVP from VBA using ADO directly? If yes, what is the correct way to do it?

I don't believe legacy ADODB supports table-valued parameters. Have you considered using XML or JSON parameters instead?

Yeah, old-school ADO can't (won't?) do this. You'll need to get a newer environment with support for ADO.NET, such as powershell or VB.NET

Yeah, I know but I could really useful for one job I need to do.

Create a wrapper procedure which accepts a json/xml string and which then populates TVP and calls the real proc. Also, when you write: I get this error, without actually specifying on which line of your example code the error occurs, it's very unhelpful

I Specified the line.
